# Call goBack for dynamic created webview with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, electron

I got a dynamic created webview. If the left mousebutton is pressed and hold, the goBack function of the webview should get called. This is working, since the console.log is shown. How do I call the .goBack() function in my looGoBack function?

```
  $('#loo').on('mousedown', function() {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(looGoBack, 1000);
  }).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });

  function looGoBack (){
    console.log('worked');
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. What is your goBack function not working? You sai looGoBack is working, so can you explain better the problem?

Comment: I do not know, how do the command goBack() on the #loo webview inside my looGoBack function.

Comment: what is the "command goBack()" for you? Your function? An electron function?

Comment: here https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewgoback

Comment: Ok so this is a problem because you can't manage directly from the webview. You have to communicate with who opened the webview and let it tell to the webview component to go back page.

Comment: Maybe its possible to load a preload.js in the webview and put the code there? How the code would be look like? (addressed to the #loo webview?)